# Отключение hover

Tags: html, css, jquery

Имею в css hover. В jquery пытаюсь его выключить:

```
$(this).off("mouseenter mouseleave");
$(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
```

Пытался 2 способами. Оба не работают. Почему?

Comment: а почему в css не выключить ?

Comment: это у меня происходит при нажатии кнопки

Comment: покажите весь код - html css js

Comment: `$(this)` это что такое? Кидайте полный код...

Comment: это текущий элемент на котором висит hover в css описан

Comment: Пожалуйста, начните задавать более развёрнутые вопросы. Хочется прочитать, понять и что-то сделать, но никак не в угадалки играть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
  $('.div').toggleClass('hover');
})
```

```css
.div{width:50px;height:50px;background-color:lightgreen;transition:background-color.3s}
.div.hover:hover{background-color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div hover"></div>
<label>unbind('hover')<label>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно такой корявый вариант использовать :)
Еще ниже вариант на jQuery

```js
let parrent = document.querySelector('.parrent');
let style=document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css'
style.textContent = '.box:hover{background-color:green}';

document.querySelector(".check").onchange =()=> {
 parrent.querySelector('style') ? style.remove() : parrent.append(style);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.box:hover{
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="switch">
<label for="switch">turn off hover</label>
</div>
```

Вариант на jQuery

```js
$(".box").hover(function(){
  $(".check").prop("checked") ? $(this).css("background", "blue") : $(this).css("background", "");
});
```

```css
.box {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
}

.box:hover {
background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">v2</div>

<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="switch">
<label for="switch">turn off hover</label>
```